Capture Screenshots on Headless VM on Azure
I have a python code that captures screenshots that I have put inside a VM on azure.
Code sample:
import os
import pyautogui
import time
from datetime import datetime

def take_screenshot():
    desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop')
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
    screenshot_file = os.path.join(desktop_path, f'{timestamp}.png')
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    screenshot.save(screenshot_file)
    print(f"Screenshot saved as '{screenshot_file}'")

# Run the screenshot function every 10 seconds
while True:
    take_screenshot()
    time.sleep(10)

When I'm connected over RDP, the code works just fine with no errors.
If I close the RDP connection, the code faces the below error:

OSError: screen grab failed

Any ideas on how I can capture screenshots when not logged in by RDP?

The error you're encountering is due to the fact that screen capture tools like pyautogui rely on an active graphical session to capture screenshots. When you disconnect from an RDP session, the graphical session is effectively closed, causing pyautogui to fail in capturing screenshots. you can use monitoring and management tools that can capture and analyse VM performance and activities.

thanks @venkat for the above, is there any available approach were i can take screenshots of the desktop without connecting to RDP?

Yes, there is option in azure portal for taking live VM screenshot by navigating to Virtual Machine > Boot diagnostics. like here


Capture Screenshots on Headless VM on Azure

The error you're encountering is due to screen capture tools like pyautogui rely on an active graphical session to capture screenshots. When you disconnect from an VM RDP session, the graphical session is effectively closed, causing pyautogui to fail in capturing screenshots. you can use monitoring and management tools that can capture and analyse VM performance and activities
There is an option in the Azure portal to take live VM screenshots by navigating to Virtual Machine > Boot diagnostics."

